# Mysql, "insert into“

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to write a SQL statement something like

```
  insert into mytable column1=value1
 and 
((column2,column3,column4) 
(select filed1, filed2,filed3 
from anothertable where filed4=a_varible))
```

I am using Mysql. The statement above only expresses what I am going to achieve. 
Is it possible? Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you're looking for something along the lines of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723163/dynamically-choosing-a-column-in-mysql, but I'm not sure, so this is only a comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want something like this:

```
Insert Into mytable(column1,column2,column3,column4)
Select 'value1',filed1, filed2,filed3 from anothertable where filed4=a_varible
```

You can include a hard coded value in your select clause and it will select that as a constant for each row.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with INSERT INTO, for example:

```
insert into mytable
(column1, column2, column3, column4)
select 'value1', filed1, filed2, filed3 
from anothertable 
where filed4 = 'some value'
```