# How to get value from a column where the column name is from a sub-query?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to ask if it is at all possible to let MySQL interpret the result of a sub-query as a table column to select from and not just a string?

What I have is are some tables in which some columns are dynamically created, and a table that stores these custom columns that are created.

In this particular implementation, I am using this to store custom fields for custom articles for a content management system we are developing.

Here is a rough sketch of the schema.

```
custom_column
-----------------------------------------------------------------
id       field_name      field_type   field_display    table_name
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1        news_author      string       Author              news
2        news_body        text         Body                news
3        news_heading     title        Heading             news
4        name             title        Name                testimonials
5        message          text         Message             testimonials
```

Considering that all articles (news, testimonials, etc.) has a corresponding custom field of the `field_type` = `title`...

I'd like to just specify a particular table/article and get just the article titles of all records, by doing something like:

```
SELECT (SELECT field_name FROM custom_columns WHERE field_type = "title" AND table_name = "testimonials") AS article_title FROM testimonials
```

And get a result along the lines of:

```
id       article_title
-----------------------
1        John Doe
2        Mary Jane
3        Justin Case
```

And not this, which is what MySQL gives me via the above query:

```
id       article_title
-----------------------
1        name
2        name
3        name
```

I can see that MySQL is interpreting `name` - the result of the sub-query - as a string, and not a column name to select from.

Of course, I can do something like:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT field_name FROM custom_columns WHERE field_type = "title" AND table_name = "testimonials") AS article_title FROM testimonials
```

And manipulate the results to get what I want within the program, like:

```
$article_title = $row->{$row->article_title};
//I use PHP, and most times use mysql_fetch_object to fetch rows from a MySQL resource.
```

But I wish to avoid querying all the the useless columns which I don't need and hopefully save resources. After all, I just need one column out of a variable amount of them, which in theory can be quite many.

I've scoured everywhere for a MySQL function that I may be missing for this to work, but never found one yet. I hope someone can point me to the right direction, or better yet, offer a better solution if one exist.

Thanks!

EDIT: To those that might be unfamiliar with the PHP syntax above, here is an equivalent scenario, but using the very common array syntax in place of PHP's syntax for objects:

```
$row[$row['article_title']];
```

Comment: Good question. I also would like to know if it's a good practice create columns on the fly. Waiting a good answer.

Comment: Well, you're getting the field name there, which is 'name'. You'll need to put that in the WHERE of the subselect, so you only return names. Then, you'll need to query the field value. But it's not clear to me where this value is stored in your schema.

Comment: An alternative would be not to use the subselect as a field, but to join on the subselect. That way, you can get all names and values, instead of just a single value.

Comment: @GolezTrol: Yep, I'm getting the name of the field, which is what I am exploiting in my current solution.

What I wanted the query to do is what it would do if I did `SELECT name FROM testimonials` and not `SELECT "name" FROM testimonials`, which the statement above does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general rule of thumb is that any time you need to dynamically look up a column in SQL (PHP is different), you should probably rethink your schema. If you ask a question on how to do that, I'm sure that you will find plenty of SO'ers willing to help.

The only dynamic MySQL I've ever found was demonstrated [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723163/dynamically-choosing-a-column-in-mysql), everything else is a variant on that. Your `$article_title = $row->{$row->article_title};` is realistically the best solution unless you can know the possible column names ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

If you do something like:

```
select table1.field, (select something from table2), ...
from table1
```

then the results of the subquery will be treated as a field. To treat the subquery's results as a table, do

```
select table1.field, subquerytable.field ...
from table1, (select field from table2) as subquerytable
...
```

Comment: I seem to get the same result with this approach. I still get the field name in the result, and not the value from that column in the intended table. But I reckon there might be something missing in my statement, but I can't tell what exactly.

`SELECT sub.field_name FROM testimonials, (SELECT field_name FROM custom_columns WHERE table_name = 'testimonials' AND field_type = 'title') AS sub`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, (SELECT field_name FROM custom_columns WHERE field_type = "title" AND table_name = "testimonials") AS article_title FROM testimonials ORDER BY id ASC
```

I could be also working without `id` but you would have to try it.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

you can use EXECUTE for this
DECLARE TabName VARCHAR(32);
--Get the table name 
select table_name into tabName from custom_columns where .....
--create the query string
set @qry = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM " , tabName , "....");
--execute the query
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
...