# Is there any way to dynamically define an operator based on a CASE in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I have a query that joins on itself to grab either the latest or oldest order record for each unique list.

```
SELECT
    lists.ordered,
    cnt1.*
FROM 
    cnt_lists as cnt1
    LEFT JOIN 
        lists
        on 
            cnt1.list_id = lists.id
    LEFT JOIN 
        cnt_lists as cnt2
        on 
            (cnt1.list_id = cnt2.list_id AND cnt1.id < cnt2.id)

WHERE
    cnt2.id is null and cnt1.list_id in ('3176', '3295', '3296') and cnt1.listable_type = 'Movie';
```

This query works great, but `lists.ordered` can be either a 0 or a 1. When `lists.ordered = 0` I would like the operator in the `on` statement to be `cnt1.id < cnt2.id` but when `lists.ordered = 1` I would like it to be reversed `cnt1.id > cnt2.id`.

Is there any way to dynamically define the operator based on a `CASE` statement? The below doesn't work, but I was playing with ideas.

```
SELECT
    lists.ordered,
    CASE
        WHEN lists.ordered = 1 THEN '>'
        ELSE '<'
    END AS operator,
    cnt1.*
FROM 
    cnt_lists as cnt1
    LEFT JOIN 
        lists
        on 
            cnt1.list_id = lists.id
    LEFT JOIN 
        cnt_lists as cnt2
        on 
            (cnt1.list_id = cnt2.list_id AND cnt1.id operator cnt2.id)

WHERE
    cnt2.id is null and cnt1.list_id in ('3176', '3295', '3296') and cnt1.listable_type = 'App\\Models\\Movie';
```

What about a way of pulling both the highest order and the lowest order for each list and I can determine which of the two records to use on the PHP side?

I am just looking for ideas as I am trying to avoid a N + 1 query problem of having to query for each list individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relying on a dynamic query is messy. You're better off pulling that operator into the `WHERE` part of the query and pair it with an OR:

```
SELECT
    lists.ordered,
    cnt1.*
FROM 
    cnt_lists as cnt1
    LEFT JOIN 
        lists
        on 
            cnt1.list_id = lists.id
    LEFT JOIN 
        cnt_lists as cnt2
        on 
            (cnt1.list_id = cnt2.list_id)

WHERE
    cnt2.id is null and cnt1.list_id in ('3176', '3295', '3296') 
    and cnt1.listable_type = 'Movie'
    AND (
       cnt2.id IS NULL /* Including this here because you have a LEFT JOIN */
       (lists.ordered = 1 AND cnt1.id < cnt2.id) OR 
       (lists.ordered = 0 AND cnt1.id > cnt2.id)
    );
```

Your other option is to put that logic into the join logic directly. This may be easier to read.

```
SELECT
    lists.ordered,
    cnt1.*
FROM 
    cnt_lists as cnt1
    LEFT JOIN 
        lists
        on 
            cnt1.list_id = lists.id
    LEFT JOIN 
        cnt_lists as cnt2
        on 
            (cnt1.list_id = cnt2.list_id AND (
       (lists.ordered = 1 AND cnt1.id < cnt2.id) OR 
       (lists.ordered = 0 AND cnt1.id > cnt2.id)
    ))

WHERE
    cnt2.id is null and cnt1.list_id in ('3176', '3295', '3296') 
    and cnt1.listable_type = 'Movie'
    ;
```

You do have the option of including `<` in your final output, but that won't be particularly useful.

If you **REALLY** want to create a dynamic query, it is hard to do in one step, [but it is definitely doable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723163/dynamically-choosing-a-column-in-mysql).

Comment: I am exploring your second option with the logic in the join statement, but I am seeing one weird thing. In this case `(lists.ordered = 1 AND cnt1.id < cnt2.id)` it is pulling the `cnt_lists` row with `order = 2` instead of `order = 2` even know there is an `order = 1` record. The other use case is pulling the last order correctly.